# My string assigning correctly into my char array (C)

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void mirror(char c[])
{
    int l = strlen(c);
    char s;
    for (int i = 0; i < l/2;i++)
    {
        s = c[i];
        c[i] = c[l-i-1];
        c[l-i-1] = s;
    }

}

void decimal_to_binary(unsigned int n,char binary_res[]){
    char r = n%2;
    unsigned int q = (n - r)/2;
    int i = 0;

    while (q != 0)
    {
        i++;
        r = n%2;
        q = (n - r)/2;
        n = q;
        printf("%d\n",q);
        binary_res[i] = r+'0';
    }
    mirror(binary_res);
}

int main(){
    int n = 34; char res[10];
    printf("%d\n",n);
    decimal_to_binary(n,res);
    printf("%s\n",res);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code which is really simple and I wanted it to convert a decimal to a binary through some repeated divisions. But there is a problem I don't understand because if I remove the +'0' when I assign the rest to the ith value in the result array, it displays nothing when I call it printf but when I add the +'0' it adds some weird characters. But I think i cmes from the fact that it is not ascii encording but UTF-8 so 0 hasn't a value of 0 but of 48. But the 0 value is for a null string so '' but when I add it to the r with +'' it shows nothing !

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here but I think there is multiple things I do wrong.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: ASCII character '0' does in fact have numerical value 48. It is exactly the same for UTF. You need to add 48 to an integer in range 0-9 for it to be a printable ASCII number.

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. Every character in ASCII encodes the same in UTF-8.

Comment: Tip: `n % 2` can also be written as `n & 1`, which seems more appropriate when dealing with binary.

Comment: Tip: `q = (n - r)/2; n = q;` => `n = (n - r)/2;` => `n = n/2;` => `n /= 2;`. Again, `>>` seems more appropriate than `/` when dealing with binary, so `n >>= 1;`

Comment: Tip: `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three bugs:

- You use `i++` too soon. You place the first bit at `binary_res[1]` when it should be placed at `binary_res[0]`.
- You don't add a terminating NUL to `binary_res`.
- You don't modify the `binary_res` at all when the `n` parameter is zero.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I check this statement '(n%2)' with loop statement and I fill the array, then I use procedure mirror to reverse the string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mirror(char c[],int l);
void decimal_to_binary(unsigned int n,char binary_res[]);


int main()
{
    int n = 40; char res[10];
    printf("%d\n",n);
    decimal_to_binary(n,res);
    printf("The binary form of number %d is %s\n",n,res);
    return 0;
}

void mirror(char c[],int l)
{
    char s;
    for (int i = 0; i < l/2;i++)
    {
        s = c[i];
        c[i] = c[l-i-1];
        c[l-i-1] = s;
    }
}

void decimal_to_binary(unsigned int n,char binary_res[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (n != 0)
   {
        switch(n%2)
        {
             case 1:
             {
                  binary_res[i]='1';
                  i++;
             }break;

             case 0:
             {
                  binary_res[i]='0';
                  i++;
             }break;
        }
        n = n/2;
    }
    binary_res[i]='\0';
    mirror(binary_res,i);
}
```